# svn+ssh protocol very slow

Tags: ssh, svn, tortoisesvn

I set up an SVN repository using the svn+ssh protocol, but file uploads are extremely slow. Uploading over SFTP shows that I'm capable of uploading at speeds of ~250KB/s. However, using TortoiseSVN & the svn+ssh protocol, I can only yield 5KB/s. Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely an old version of SSH. [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/656814/ssh-in-windows-has-very-slow-transfer-rates/675050#675050) explains how to fix it. TL;DR install Cygwin and try to use the ssh version that comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try add following to your `~/.ssh/config` SSH config:

```
Compression yes
CompressionLevel 9
```

Comment: I did that, restarted ssh, but I'm still experiencing slow speeds.

Comment: This is client site setting right?

Comment: Both sides. Note that `CompressionLevel` is deprecated meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "-share" option on TortoisePlink. This enables ssh connection sharing. I got a 80x speedup from this with TortoiseSVN on Windows.
For TortoiseSVN add "-share" to the "SSH client" command under "Settings->Network".